# Multiple divs go out of bounds even though there's no rules that should make it do so

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I have this rather primitive Slideshow, but for some reason, the CSS is messed up. The flex-container and the carousel-container seem to be bigger than the original image, which should not be the case. What am I doing wrong?

```js
class CarouselController {

    defaultSettings = {
        loop: true,
        delay: 3000,
        autoplay: true
    }

    /**
     * @@param {object} settings
     */
    constructor(settings) {
        this.carousel = settings.element;
        delete settings.element;

        this.current = 0;
        this.hooks = {};
        this.settings = settings;

        if (!this.carousel) {
            throw 'A carousel element is required. For example: new CarouselController({ element: document.getElementById(\'carousel\') })';
        }

        /**
         * Sanitize `loop` setting
         */
        this.addFilter('setting.loop', value => {
            return String(value).toLowerCase() === 'true';
        });

        /**
         * Sanitize `delay` setting
         */
        this.addFilter('setting.delay', value => parseInt(value));

        /**
         * Sanitize `autoplay` setting
         */
        this.addFilter('setting.autoplay', value => {
            return String(value).toLowerCase() === 'true';
        });

        // Autoplay on init.
        if (this.getSetting('autoplay')) {
            this.play();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get the carousel container element.
     * @@returns {Element}
     */
    getCarousel() {
        return this.carousel;
    }

    /**
     * Get a setting value.
     * @@param {string} name
     * @@param defaultValue
     * @@returns {*}
     */
    getSetting(name, defaultValue) {
        if (!defaultValue && name in this.defaultSettings) {
            defaultValue = this.defaultSettings[name]
        }

        /**
         * Apply value filters.
         * @@example carousel.addFilter('setting.delay', function(value) { return value + 500; });
         */
        return this.applyFilters(`setting.${name}`, name in this.settings ? this.settings[name] : defaultValue);
    }

    /**
     * Get hooks by type and name. Ordered by priority.
     * @@param {string} type
     * @@param {string} name
     * @@returns {array}
     */
    getHooks(type, name) {
        let hooks = [];

        if (type in this.hooks) {
            let localHooks = this.hooks[type];
            localHooks = localHooks.filter(el => el.name === name);
            localHooks = localHooks.sort((a, b) => a.priority - b.priority);
            hooks = hooks.concat(localHooks);
        }

        return hooks;
    }

    /**
     * Add a hook.
     * @@param {string} type
     * @@param {object} hookMeta
     */
    addHook(type, hookMeta) {

        // Create new local hook type array.
        if (!(type in this.hooks)) {
            this.hooks[type] = [];
        }

        this.hooks[type].push(hookMeta);
    }

    /**
     * Add action listener.
     * @@param {string} action Name of action to trigger callback on.
     * @@param {function} callback
     * @@param {number} priority
     */
    addAction(action, callback, priority = 10) {
        this.addHook('actions', {
            name: action,
            callback: callback,
            priority: priority
        });
    }

    /**
     * Trigger an action.
     * @@param {string} name Name of action to run.
     * @@param {*} args Arguments passed to the callback function.
     */
    doAction(name, ...args) {
        this.getHooks('actions', name).forEach(hook => {
           hook.callback(...args);
        });
    }

    /**
     * Register filter.
     * @@param {string} filter Name of filter to trigger callback on.
     * @@param {function} callback
     * @@param {number} priority
     */
    addFilter(filter, callback, priority = 10) {
        this.addHook('filters', {
            name: filter,
            callback: callback,
            priority: priority
        });
    }

    /**
     * Apply all named filters to a value.
     * @@param {string} name Name of action to run.
     * @@param {*} value The value to be mutated.
     * @@param {*} args Arguments passed to the callback function.
     * @@returns {*}
     */
    applyFilters(name, value, ...args) {
        this.getHooks('filters', name).forEach(hook => {
            value = hook.callback(value, ...args);
        });

        return value;
    }

    /**
     * Get all the children (slides) elements.
     * @@returns {Element[]}
     */
    getSlides() {
        return Array.from(this.getCarousel().children);
    }

    /**
     * Get a specific slide by index.
     * @@param {int} index
     * @@returns {Element|null}
     */
    getSlide(index) {
        return this.getSlides()[index];
    }

    /**
     * Show a specific slide by index.
     * @@param {int} index
     * @@returns {int}
     */
    goTo(index) {
        const slides = this.getSlides();
        const slide = this.getSlide(index);

        if (slide) {
            slides.forEach((el) => {
                el.classList.remove('active');
            });

            slide.classList.add('active');

            this.current = slides.indexOf(slide);

            /**
             * Trigger goto event.
             * @@example carousel.addAction('goto', function(slide, index) { ... });
             */
            this.doAction('goto', slide, this.current);
        }

        return this.current;
    }

    /**
     * Show the next slide (if has one).
     */
    next() {
        let replay = false;

        // Check if carousel is looping through slides automatically.
        if (this.playing) {
            replay = true;
        }

        const slides = this.getSlides();
        let nextIndex = this.current + 1;

        // If the next slide is greater than the total, reset to 0 if looping else use -1 to stop `goTo` method.
        if (nextIndex > (slides.length - 1)) {
            if (this.getSetting('loop')) {
                nextIndex = 0;
            } else {
                nextIndex = -1;
            }
        }

        // Only go to slide if next index is valid.
        if (nextIndex >= 0) {
            this.goTo(nextIndex);

            // Continue with auto play.
            if (replay) {
                this.play();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Show the previous slide (if has one).
     */
    previous() {
        let replay = false;

        // Check if carousel is looping through slides automatically.
        if (this.playing) {
            replay = true;
        }

        const slides = this.getSlides();
        let prevIndex = this.current - 1;

        // If the prev slide is less than 0, reset to the last slide if looping else use -1 to stop `goTo` method.
        if (prevIndex < 0) {
            if (this.getSetting('loop')) {
                prevIndex = slides.length - 1;
            } else {
                prevIndex = -1;
            }
        }

        // Only go to slide if next index is valid.
        if (prevIndex >= 0) {
            this.goTo(prevIndex);

            // Continue with auto play.
            if (replay) {
                this.play();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Automatically go to the next slide (or start if loop is true).
     * @@returns {number}
     */
    play() {
        this.stop();

        this.goTo(this.current);

        this.playing = setInterval(() => {
            this.next();
        }, this.getSetting('delay'));

        return this.playing;
    }

    /**
     * Stop the automatic carousel if running.
     */
    stop() {
        if (this.playing) {
            clearInterval(this.playing);
        }
    }


}

/**
 * Get the carousel container element.
 * @@type {Element}
 */
const carouselContainer = document.querySelector('.carousel-container');

/**
 * Create a new controller instance for our carousel.
 * @@type {CarouselController}
 */
const carousel = new CarouselController({
    element: carouselContainer.querySelector('.carousel'),
    loop: true,
    delay: 3000,
    autoplay: true
});

/**
 * Lazy load each image only when the slide is in view.
 */
carousel.addAction('goto', function(slide, index) {
    let images = [];

    if (slide.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'img') {
        images.push(slide);
    } else {
        images.concat(slide.querySelectorAll('img'));
    }

    images.forEach((img) => {
        if (!img.src && img.dataset.src) {
            img.src = img.dataset.src;
        }
    });
});
```

```css
:root {
    --carousel-width: 70vw;
    /*--carousel-height: calc(calc(calc(9 / 16) * var(--carousel-width)));*/
    --carousel-height: 70vh;
}

.carousel {
  width: var(--carousel-width);
  height: var(--carousel-height);
  contain: strict;
  margin-top: 1vw;
  border-radius: 3vmin;
  max-height: 1000px;
  max-width: 1000px;
}
/* Hide all carousel slides by default */
.carousel-container .carousel > * {
  display: none;
}

/* Only show the active carousel slide */
.carousel-container .carousel > *.active {
  display: block;
}

.carousel-container {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    max-height: 50vh;
}
.flex-container {
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="carousel-container">
  <div class="flex-container">
    <div class="carousel">

      <img data-src="https://picsum.photos/500/300" src="https://picsum.photos/500/300" />
      <img loading="lazy" data-src="https://picsum.photos/500/300" />
      <img loading="lazy" data-src="https://picsum.photos/500/300" />
      <img loading="lazy" data-src="https://picsum.photos/500/300" />
      <img loading="lazy" data-src="https://picsum.photos/500/300" />
      <img loading="lazy" data-src="https://picsum.photos/500/300" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

There are these two variables for the carousel height and width, but if I change them to anything else than this or a similar `vh` / `vw` value the picture just disappears. That is also strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the flex-container and the carousel-container seem to be bigger than the original image

Adding `display:flex` will make `carousel-container` to align width with child. Also, height will be restricted because of `max-height: 50vh;`. Remove `max-height: 50vh;` to have an exact match of height and width.

```
.carousel-container {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    max-height: 50vh;
    display: flex;
}
```

Updating `width` and `height` to `100%` or `auto` make it dynamic and not dependent upon viewport.

```
.carousel {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-top: 1vw;
    border-radius: 3vmin;
    max-height: 1000px;
    max-width: 1000px;
}
```

Also remove `contain:strict;` as
[image]

Use `contain:strict;` only when the height and width are known and fixed.

```
.carousel {
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    contain: strict;
    margin-top: 1vw;
    border-radius: 3vmin;
    max-height: 1000px;
    max-width: 1000px;
}
```

**Snippet with `contain:strict` :**

```js
class CarouselController {

    defaultSettings = {
        loop: true,
        delay: 3000,
        autoplay: true
    }

    /**
     * @@param {object} settings
     */
    constructor(settings) {
        this.carousel = settings.element;
        delete settings.element;

        this.current = 0;
        this.hooks = {};
        this.settings = settings;

        if (!this.carousel) {
            throw 'A carousel element is required. For example: new CarouselController({ element: document.getElementById(\'carousel\') })';
        }

        /**
         * Sanitize `loop` setting
         */
        this.addFilter('setting.loop', value => {
            return String(value).toLowerCase() === 'true';
        });

        /**
         * Sanitize `delay` setting
         */
        this.addFilter('setting.delay', value => parseInt(value));

        /**
         * Sanitize `autoplay` setting
         */
        this.addFilter('setting.autoplay', value => {
            return String(value).toLowerCase() === 'true';
        });

        // Autoplay on init.
        if (this.getSetting('autoplay')) {
            this.play();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get the carousel container element.
     * @@returns {Element}
     */
    getCarousel() {
        return this.carousel;
    }

    /**
     * Get a setting value.
     * @@param {string} name
     * @@param defaultValue
     * @@returns {*}
     */
    getSetting(name, defaultValue) {
        if (!defaultValue && name in this.defaultSettings) {
            defaultValue = this.defaultSettings[name]
        }

        /**
         * Apply value filters.
         * @@example carousel.addFilter('setting.delay', function(value) { return value + 500; });
         */
        return this.applyFilters(`setting.${name}`, name in this.settings ? this.settings[name] : defaultValue);
    }

    /**
     * Get hooks by type and name. Ordered by priority.
     * @@param {string} type
     * @@param {string} name
     * @@returns {array}
     */
    getHooks(type, name) {
        let hooks = [];

        if (type in this.hooks) {
            let localHooks = this.hooks[type];
            localHooks = localHooks.filter(el => el.name === name);
            localHooks = localHooks.sort((a, b) => a.priority - b.priority);
            hooks = hooks.concat(localHooks);
        }

        return hooks;
    }

    /**
     * Add a hook.
     * @@param {string} type
     * @@param {object} hookMeta
     */
    addHook(type, hookMeta) {

        // Create new local hook type array.
        if (!(type in this.hooks)) {
            this.hooks[type] = [];
        }

        this.hooks[type].push(hookMeta);
    }

    /**
     * Add action listener.
     * @@param {string} action Name of action to trigger callback on.
     * @@param {function} callback
     * @@param {number} priority
     */
    addAction(action, callback, priority = 10) {
        this.addHook('actions', {
            name: action,
            callback: callback,
            priority: priority
        });
    }

    /**
     * Trigger an action.
     * @@param {string} name Name of action to run.
     * @@param {*} args Arguments passed to the callback function.
     */
    doAction(name, ...args) {
        this.getHooks('actions', name).forEach(hook => {
           hook.callback(...args);
        });
    }

    /**
     * Register filter.
     * @@param {string} filter Name of filter to trigger callback on.
     * @@param {function} callback
     * @@param {number} priority
     */
    addFilter(filter, callback, priority = 10) {
        this.addHook('filters', {
            name: filter,
            callback: callback,
            priority: priority
        });
    }

    /**
     * Apply all named filters to a value.
     * @@param {string} name Name of action to run.
     * @@param {*} value The value to be mutated.
     * @@param {*} args Arguments passed to the callback function.
     * @@returns {*}
     */
    applyFilters(name, value, ...args) {
        this.getHooks('filters', name).forEach(hook => {
            value = hook.callback(value, ...args);
        });

        return value;
    }

    /**
     * Get all the children (slides) elements.
     * @@returns {Element[]}
     */
    getSlides() {
        return Array.from(this.getCarousel().children);
    }

    /**
     * Get a specific slide by index.
     * @@param {int} index
     * @@returns {Element|null}
     */
    getSlide(index) {
        return this.getSlides()[index];
    }

    /**
     * Show a specific slide by index.
     * @@param {int} index
     * @@returns {int}
     */
    goTo(index) {
        const slides = this.getSlides();
        const slide = this.getSlide(index);

        if (slide) {
            slides.forEach((el) => {
                el.classList.remove('active');
            });

            slide.classList.add('active');

            this.current = slides.indexOf(slide);

            /**
             * Trigger goto event.
             * @@example carousel.addAction('goto', function(slide, index) { ... });
             */
            this.doAction('goto', slide, this.current);
        }

        return this.current;
    }

    /**
     * Show the next slide (if has one).
     */
    next() {
        let replay = false;

        // Check if carousel is looping through slides automatically.
        if (this.playing) {
            replay = true;
        }

        const slides = this.getSlides();
        let nextIndex = this.current + 1;

        // If the next slide is greater than the total, reset to 0 if looping else use -1 to stop `goTo` method.
        if (nextIndex > (slides.length - 1)) {
            if (this.getSetting('loop')) {
                nextIndex = 0;
            } else {
                nextIndex = -1;
            }
        }

        // Only go to slide if next index is valid.
        if (nextIndex >= 0) {
            this.goTo(nextIndex);

            // Continue with auto play.
            if (replay) {
                this.play();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Show the previous slide (if has one).
     */
    previous() {
        let replay = false;

        // Check if carousel is looping through slides automatically.
        if (this.playing) {
            replay = true;
        }

        const slides = this.getSlides();
        let prevIndex = this.current - 1;

        // If the prev slide is less than 0, reset to the last slide if looping else use -1 to stop `goTo` method.
        if (prevIndex < 0) {
            if (this.getSetting('loop')) {
                prevIndex = slides.length - 1;
            } else {
                prevIndex = -1;
            }
        }

        // Only go to slide if next index is valid.
        if (prevIndex >= 0) {
            this.goTo(prevIndex);

            // Continue with auto play.
            if (replay) {
                this.play();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Automatically go to the next slide (or start if loop is true).
     * @@returns {number}
     */
    play() {
        this.stop();

        this.goTo(this.current);

        this.playing = setInterval(() => {
            this.next();
        }, this.getSetting('delay'));

        return this.playing;
    }

    /**
     * Stop the automatic carousel if running.
     */
    stop() {
        if (this.playing) {
            clearInterval(this.playing);
        }
    }


}

/**
 * Get the carousel container element.
 * @@type {Element}
 */
const carouselContainer = document.querySelector('.carousel-container');

/**
 * Create a new controller instance for our carousel.
 * @@type {CarouselController}
 */
const carousel = new CarouselController({
    element: carouselContainer.querySelector('.carousel'),
    loop: true,
    delay: 3000,
    autoplay: true
});

/**
 * Lazy load each image only when the slide is in view.
 */
carousel.addAction('goto', function(slide, index) {
    let images = [];

    if (slide.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'img') {
        images.push(slide);
    } else {
        images.concat(slide.querySelectorAll('img'));
    }

    images.forEach((img) => {
        if (!img.src && img.dataset.src) {
            img.src = img.dataset.src;
        }
    });
});
```

```css
:root {
    --carousel-width: 70vw;
    /*--carousel-height: calc(calc(calc(9 / 16) * var(--carousel-width)));*/
    --carousel-height: 70vh;
}

.carousel {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  contain: strict;
  margin-top: 1vw;
  border-radius: 3vmin;
  max-height: 1000px;
  max-width: 1000px;
}
/* Hide all carousel slides by default */
.carousel-container .carousel > * {
  display: none;
}

/* Only show the active carousel slide */
.carousel-container .carousel > *.active {
  display: block;
}

.carousel-container {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    max-height: 50vh;
    display: flex;
}
.flex-container {
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="carousel-container">
  <div class="flex-container">
    <div class="carousel">

      <img data-src="https://picsum.photos/500/300" src="https://picsum.photos/500/300" />
      <img loading="lazy" data-src="https://picsum.photos/500/300" />
      <img loading="lazy" data-src="https://picsum.photos/500/300" />
      <img loading="lazy" data-src="https://picsum.photos/500/300" />
      <img loading="lazy" data-src="https://picsum.photos/500/300" />
      <img loading="lazy" data-src="https://picsum.photos/500/300" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Snippet without `contain:strict`:**

```js
class CarouselController {

    defaultSettings = {
        loop: true,
        delay: 3000,
        autoplay: true
    }

    /**
     * @@param {object} settings
     */
    constructor(settings) {
        this.carousel = settings.element;
        delete settings.element;

        this.current = 0;
        this.hooks = {};
        this.settings = settings;

        if (!this.carousel) {
            throw 'A carousel element is required. For example: new CarouselController({ element: document.getElementById(\'carousel\') })';
        }

        /**
         * Sanitize `loop` setting
         */
        this.addFilter('setting.loop', value => {
            return String(value).toLowerCase() === 'true';
        });

        /**
         * Sanitize `delay` setting
         */
        this.addFilter('setting.delay', value => parseInt(value));

        /**
         * Sanitize `autoplay` setting
         */
        this.addFilter('setting.autoplay', value => {
            return String(value).toLowerCase() === 'true';
        });

        // Autoplay on init.
        if (this.getSetting('autoplay')) {
            this.play();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get the carousel container element.
     * @@returns {Element}
     */
    getCarousel() {
        return this.carousel;
    }

    /**
     * Get a setting value.
     * @@param {string} name
     * @@param defaultValue
     * @@returns {*}
     */
    getSetting(name, defaultValue) {
        if (!defaultValue && name in this.defaultSettings) {
            defaultValue = this.defaultSettings[name]
        }

        /**
         * Apply value filters.
         * @@example carousel.addFilter('setting.delay', function(value) { return value + 500; });
         */
        return this.applyFilters(`setting.${name}`, name in this.settings ? this.settings[name] : defaultValue);
    }

    /**
     * Get hooks by type and name. Ordered by priority.
     * @@param {string} type
     * @@param {string} name
     * @@returns {array}
     */
    getHooks(type, name) {
        let hooks = [];

        if (type in this.hooks) {
            let localHooks = this.hooks[type];
            localHooks = localHooks.filter(el => el.name === name);
            localHooks = localHooks.sort((a, b) => a.priority - b.priority);
            hooks = hooks.concat(localHooks);
        }

        return hooks;
    }

    /**
     * Add a hook.
     * @@param {string} type
     * @@param {object} hookMeta
     */
    addHook(type, hookMeta) {

        // Create new local hook type array.
        if (!(type in this.hooks)) {
            this.hooks[type] = [];
        }

        this.hooks[type].push(hookMeta);
    }

    /**
     * Add action listener.
     * @@param {string} action Name of action to trigger callback on.
     * @@param {function} callback
     * @@param {number} priority
     */
    addAction(action, callback, priority = 10) {
        this.addHook('actions', {
            name: action,
            callback: callback,
            priority: priority
        });
    }

    /**
     * Trigger an action.
     * @@param {string} name Name of action to run.
     * @@param {*} args Arguments passed to the callback function.
     */
    doAction(name, ...args) {
        this.getHooks('actions', name).forEach(hook => {
           hook.callback(...args);
        });
    }

    /**
     * Register filter.
     * @@param {string} filter Name of filter to trigger callback on.
     * @@param {function} callback
     * @@param {number} priority
     */
    addFilter(filter, callback, priority = 10) {
        this.addHook('filters', {
            name: filter,
            callback: callback,
            priority: priority
        });
    }

    /**
     * Apply all named filters to a value.
     * @@param {string} name Name of action to run.
     * @@param {*} value The value to be mutated.
     * @@param {*} args Arguments passed to the callback function.
     * @@returns {*}
     */
    applyFilters(name, value, ...args) {
        this.getHooks('filters', name).forEach(hook => {
            value = hook.callback(value, ...args);
        });

        return value;
    }

    /**
     * Get all the children (slides) elements.
     * @@returns {Element[]}
     */
    getSlides() {
        return Array.from(this.getCarousel().children);
    }

    /**
     * Get a specific slide by index.
     * @@param {int} index
     * @@returns {Element|null}
     */
    getSlide(index) {
        return this.getSlides()[index];
    }

    /**
     * Show a specific slide by index.
     * @@param {int} index
     * @@returns {int}
     */
    goTo(index) {
        const slides = this.getSlides();
        const slide = this.getSlide(index);

        if (slide) {
            slides.forEach((el) => {
                el.classList.remove('active');
            });

            slide.classList.add('active');

            this.current = slides.indexOf(slide);

            /**
             * Trigger goto event.
             * @@example carousel.addAction('goto', function(slide, index) { ... });
             */
            this.doAction('goto', slide, this.current);
        }

        return this.current;
    }

    /**
     * Show the next slide (if has one).
     */
    next() {
        let replay = false;

        // Check if carousel is looping through slides automatically.
        if (this.playing) {
            replay = true;
        }

        const slides = this.getSlides();
        let nextIndex = this.current + 1;

        // If the next slide is greater than the total, reset to 0 if looping else use -1 to stop `goTo` method.
        if (nextIndex > (slides.length - 1)) {
            if (this.getSetting('loop')) {
                nextIndex = 0;
            } else {
                nextIndex = -1;
            }
        }

        // Only go to slide if next index is valid.
        if (nextIndex >= 0) {
            this.goTo(nextIndex);

            // Continue with auto play.
            if (replay) {
                this.play();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Show the previous slide (if has one).
     */
    previous() {
        let replay = false;

        // Check if carousel is looping through slides automatically.
        if (this.playing) {
            replay = true;
        }

        const slides = this.getSlides();
        let prevIndex = this.current - 1;

        // If the prev slide is less than 0, reset to the last slide if looping else use -1 to stop `goTo` method.
        if (prevIndex < 0) {
            if (this.getSetting('loop')) {
                prevIndex = slides.length - 1;
            } else {
                prevIndex = -1;
            }
        }

        // Only go to slide if next index is valid.
        if (prevIndex >= 0) {
            this.goTo(prevIndex);

            // Continue with auto play.
            if (replay) {
                this.play();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Automatically go to the next slide (or start if loop is true).
     * @@returns {number}
     */
    play() {
        this.stop();

        this.goTo(this.current);

        this.playing = setInterval(() => {
            this.next();
        }, this.getSetting('delay'));

        return this.playing;
    }

    /**
     * Stop the automatic carousel if running.
     */
    stop() {
        if (this.playing) {
            clearInterval(this.playing);
        }
    }


}

/**
 * Get the carousel container element.
 * @@type {Element}
 */
const carouselContainer = document.querySelector('.carousel-container');

/**
 * Create a new controller instance for our carousel.
 * @@type {CarouselController}
 */
const carousel = new CarouselController({
    element: carouselContainer.querySelector('.carousel'),
    loop: true,
    delay: 3000,
    autoplay: true
});

/**
 * Lazy load each image only when the slide is in view.
 */
carousel.addAction('goto', function(slide, index) {
    let images = [];

    if (slide.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'img') {
        images.push(slide);
    } else {
        images.concat(slide.querySelectorAll('img'));
    }

    images.forEach((img) => {
        if (!img.src && img.dataset.src) {
            img.src = img.dataset.src;
        }
    });
});
```

```css
:root {
    --carousel-width: 70vw;
    /*--carousel-height: calc(calc(calc(9 / 16) * var(--carousel-width)));*/
    --carousel-height: 70vh;
}

.carousel {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-top: 1vw;
  border-radius: 3vmin;
  max-height: 1000px;
  max-width: 1000px;
}
/* Hide all carousel slides by default */
.carousel-container .carousel > * {
  display: none;
}

/* Only show the active carousel slide */
.carousel-container .carousel > *.active {
  display: block;
}

.carousel-container {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    max-height: 50vh;
    display: flex;
}
.flex-container {
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="carousel-container">
  <div class="flex-container">
    <div class="carousel">

      <img data-src="https://picsum.photos/500/300" src="https://picsum.photos/500/300" />
      <img loading="lazy" data-src="https://picsum.photos/500/300" />
      <img loading="lazy" data-src="https://picsum.photos/500/300" />
      <img loading="lazy" data-src="https://picsum.photos/500/300" />
      <img loading="lazy" data-src="https://picsum.photos/500/300" />
      <img loading="lazy" data-src="https://picsum.photos/500/300" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: At least here in StackOverflow the carousel-container is as wide as the viewport for me. The other divs appear to be in bounds now though. Any clue how to fix it?

Comment: Nevermind in the real implementation works, I've accepted your answer :-)

Comment: @Munchkin Hey, good if it works. ^_^ thanks for accepting and voting.